# php variable inside href inside if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, href

I am trying to make a thumbnail image clickable so that when clicked, it shows the full size image, but I keep getting a PHP error and I'm not sure why. This is a Wordpress site. I suspect it has something to do with the variable that's inside the URL, but I need some guidance. I've searched stack for almost 8 hours now...Here is my code:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<a href="'get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full');'">';
    the_post_thumbnail('cb-thumb-600-crop');
    echo '</a>';
        } else {
```

Comment: *"but I keep getting a PHP error"* - Being what exactly?

Comment: Lovely. You know, when a question is asked, there contains a question mark and mine had one, yours didn't. So, in turn, no reply, you get none back from me.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer for other's reference. Thanks!

Comment: sorry @Fred-ii- . I was gone over the weekend so I didn't get to check back on your question, but thanks the offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's wrong on your code is this:

```
echo '<a href="'get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full');'">';
```

should be:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full') . '">';
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks Jed!

Comment: would you recommend I add esc_url to this? like this:

echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' ) ) . '">';

Comment: Yes since it will sanitize the URL, i'm not into Wordpress so I don't know how it really works. So you might have to check depending on you needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
$anything=get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full');
$anythings=the_post_thumbnail('cb-thumb-600-crop');
echo '<a href="'.$anything.'">'.$anythings.'</a>';
    } else {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
echo  '<a href="'get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full');'">';
```

You forgot the dots between the single quotes near "get_" and ");"

It should look something like this:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full') . '">';
```

Good luck and keep coding! :)